# Extract IV from the encrypted string

Tags: php, encryption

I have a function to encrypt and decrypt the data. I want to get the IV of the encrypted string while decrypting.

**Is there any possible way to extract the iv of an encrypted string in php?**

I am using php's `mcrypt_encrypt` function with `RIJNDAEL_128`.

Comment: You have to include the IV yourself to the encrypted string (normally encoded and delimited by a certain character), so you will know how to extract it from there.

Comment: For now,i am hardcoding the iv in my code while encrypting. I need to extract the same iv while decryptng! Is that possible?

Comment: The IV should not be hardcoded, it should be different (random) for every encrypted string. Either you store the cyphertext and the IV separately, or you concatenate both yourself to one string. If you do it yourself, then you have to find a way, so you can later split it to IV and cyphertext. One possible example you can find [here](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#bcrypt), search for the method `encryptTwofish()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IV will not be included in the encrypted output. It is your responsibility to pass this IV value to whomever needs to decrypt your data.

A common approach is prepend the IV to the ciphertex, so that the first sixteen bytes will be the IV for your AES decryption operation.

As mentioned in the comments, IV values should be randomly generated. Hard-coding an IV will lessen the security of your system.